# Defining LongClick events for layout within listview item

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

Within the XML layout of my listview items, I use:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    android:onClick="event"
</RelativeLayout>
```

Which then calls the method in my activity:

```
public void event(View view)
{
    final int position = list.getPositionForView((View) view.getParent());
    // do action here
}
```

However, there is no XML definition for `android:onLongClick` (unfortunately).

Using this method I am able to call different methods depending on which layout in the item was pressed. I ran into this problem when I decided that I needed to add an `OnLongClickListener` to one of the layouts. As this listener needs to be done on the item-level (per row in the list), and not for the entire list, I don't think I can add this listener to my activity.

My first attempt to solve this was to put attach the `OnLongClickListener` to the layout in the `getView()` method of the adapter (effectively adding a listener to each row in the list) - which worked well. The only problem is that you don't seem to be able to refresh the list itself from within the adapter (as far as I know).

Keeping in mind that the event needs to be able to refresh the data behind the list (e.g, I need to call `setAdapter()` on the list to refresh it), how can I correctly define an `OnLongClickListener` event for a layout within each `ListView` item (not the entire list item itself)?

Edit: The adapter functions `onNotifyDataSetChanged()` and `onNotifyDataSetInvalidated()` do not seem to refresh the list either.

Comment: From within your adapter you can call `this.notifyDatasetChanged()` or `this.notiftDatasetInvalidated()`. That should refresh your list.

Comment: @indivisible Thanks, but neither of these functions seem to refresh the list when I call them from within the adapter. I've seen other users saying this too. Is there an alternative?

Comment: If it is not working then I would look more closely at your current code as it should be. Finding a workaround would only be masking potentially buggy code that could blow up on you later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out!

In my adapter, I added a new parameter to the constructor, passing in a reference to my activity, like so:

```
private MyActivity parentActivity;

public MyAdapter(MyActivity pa)
{
    this.parentActivity = pa;
}
```

In my `MyActivity` class, I defined a public method that would refresh the listview:

```
public void loadData()
{
    // calls an asynchronous task to refresh the list
    new LoadDataTask().execute();
}
```

Then, finally, in `MyAdapter`, I then simply call `this.parentActivity.loadData();` to refresh the list. Simples!

Comment: Ah, you didn't say that you wanted to refresh the data backing the ListView and not the representation of that data. I had assumed that the dataset had already changed and you couldn't get the changes updated in your UI. You should accept your answer and perhaps have a look at your question to see if you can make it a bit clearer what you were trying to do for future readers.

Comment: Can't accept my own answer until 48 hours have passed. Perhaps I should have said `refresh the data` instead of `refresh the list`. My bad. Thanks for your help nonetheless.